# React get Array from external .js that loaded async

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want in my react app to load another .js which contain a variable array

```
arrayCode.js
var arrayCode=["1","2","3","4","5"];

in component.js

componentDidMount() {
const script = document.createElement("script");

        script.src = "/arrayCode.js";
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);

}
```

and some how load the arrayCode in component's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your arrayCode.js is always going to be a simple array, I would recommend that you change it to arrayCode.json and then use a GET request to retrieve the json and parse it using builtin `JSON.parse`.

That said, if there is some specific reason why you need it to be a .js file, then you can always do a GET and `eval` on the response.

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/arrayCode.js')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(text => {
            eval(text);

            // You now have access to arrayCode var
            console.log(arrayCode);
            this.setState({
                array: arrayCode
            })
        });
}
```

If you are okay with moving arrayCode.js to arrayCode.json, then your arrayCode.json will look like

```
["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

and your `componentWillMount` can become:

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/arrayCode.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            const array = JSON.parse(json);

            // You now have access to arrayCode var
            console.log(array);
            this.setState({
                array,
            })
        });
}
```